# How to sort a Python dictionary by keys?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I was trying to sort a dictionary by keys but whenever I printed it back, it returned indexes in random order.

```
students = {'John' : 23, 'Harry' :20, 'Adam' : 25}
```

I have a dictionary like this. I want to sort it using keys in ascending order i.e. I want the output as:

```
{'Adam' :25,'Harry' :20,'John' :23}
```

Here's what I tried to solve this.

1. I used **sorted(students.items())**
   But it returned the randomly sorted  dictionary.
2. I tried

   `sorted(students.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])`

But, this also didn't work.

3. I also tried **collections.OrderedDict**

```
import collections
sortedstudents =collections.OrderedDict(students.items())
```

This actually sorted the list but the output was not a Python dictionary. It was like :

```
{('Adam', 25),('Harry',20),('John',23)}
```

But, I want output like this :

```
{'Adam' :25,'Harry' :20,'John' :23}
```

**Can anybody please help me solve this?**

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: In general if you find yourself wanting to sort a dictionary (as opposed to operating on sorted elements from a dictionary) then you need to reconsider using a dictionary. Why do you need to sort it? If it's just for printing then you can iterate on `sorted(students.items())` and print the elements that way, no sorting of the actual dictionary required.

Comment: Dictionaries, conceptually, do not have an order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
students = {'John' : 23, 'Harry' :20, 'Adam' : 25}
    
sorted_students = dict(sorted(students.items()))
print(sorted_students)
```